# remove array items from array list in jquery using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove array item on each click. Onclick of `get_values` button, displays array items in front of delete button/link. I need to remove those item on each click of delete button. It deletes whole item, but i want one by one. Plz help me. I am new to jquery.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="array_container"> 
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<label>State</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<label>Color</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<input type="button" name="get_value" id="get_value" value="Get Value"/> 
</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#get_value").click(function () 
    {   //causing error here removed the array in name value
        var ListOfArray = [];
        var option = $('input:text[name=name1]').map(function() 
        {   
           return $(this).val();
        }).get().join();
        $("input:text[name=name1]").val("");
        ListOfArray.push(option);
        for (var i= 0; i < ListOfArray.length; i++)
        {  
            alert(i); //alert(ListOfArray.length);
            var newList = "<a href='#' onClick='removeArray(" + i + ");'return false;> DELETE </a> " + option + " <br>";
            alert(newList); //alert(i);
        };
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += newList;
        return true;
    });
    function removeArray(i)  
    {   
        var ListOfArray = [];
        alert('after removed array.'+i);
        ListOfArray.splice(i,1);
        var newList = "";
        //console.log(ListOfArray); 
        for (var i = 0; i < ListOfArray.length; i++)
        {   //You refer to option here for element, which should be replaced by proper index of array
          alert(ListOfArray.length);  alert(i); 
          newList += "<a href='#' onClick='removeArray(" + i + ");'return false;> DELETE </a> " + ListOfArray[i] + " <br>";
           alert(i); 
        };
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = newList;
        return true;
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move `var ListOfArray = [];` to global scope. in simple language write the statement outside functions and only once.

Comment: posted 2 days ago ? [how-to-remove-array-items-from-array-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970814/how-to-remove-array-items-from-array-list/25971014)

Answer (score 1):

Currently ListofArray is local variable to the onclick handler function and removeArray function cant access it from the outer scope. In addition you have declared a new variable inside removeArray . What you need to do is to keep the ListofArray variable as a single instance which is shared by both the functions.

Like

```js
var ListOfArray = [];
$("#get_value").click(function () 
{   //causing error here removed the array in name value
 
 var option = $('input:text[name=name1]').map(function() 
 {   
    return $(this).val();
 }).get().join();
 $("input:text[name=name1]").val("");
 ListOfArray.push(option);
 for (var i= 0; i < ListOfArray.length; i++)
 {  
  alert(i); //alert(ListOfArray.length);
  var newList = "<a href='#' onClick='removeArray(" + i + ");'return false;> DELETE </a> " + option + " <br>";
  alert(newList); //alert(i);
 };
 document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += newList;
 return true;
});
function removeArray(i)  
{   
 alert('after removed array.'+i);
 ListOfArray.splice(i,1);
 var newList = "";
 //console.log(ListOfArray); 
 for (var i = 0; i < ListOfArray.length; i++)
 {   //You refer to option here for element, which should be replaced by proper index of array
   alert(ListOfArray.length);  alert(i); 
   newList += "<a href='#' onClick='removeArray(" + i + ");'return false;> DELETE </a> " + ListOfArray[i] + " <br>";
    alert(i); 
 };
 document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = newList;
 return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="array_container"> 
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<label>State</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<label>Color</label>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> 
<input type="button" name="get_value" id="get_value" value="Get Value"/> 
</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```